# Angular: HttpInterceptor with different handling for specific situation

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I know there is in Angular the HTTPInterceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class HTTPRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(
        (_response: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          // nothing to do ... ... used for sending anyway...
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         ... // display message
        }
```

To my understanding this is applied to all of my requests. Now I have the situation that for one specific request I do not want to apply the regular error handling. Is there an easy way to achieve this? e.g. setting some special parameters in my request

```
this.http.get<MyInfo>(`getlastInfo/${id}`).toPromise();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BELLIL suggested, reading a header is easier than relying on the url. You could still remove the header before sending it to the server :

```html
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const doSpecificHandling = req.headers.has('Angular-Error-Handler');

    return next.handle(req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.delete('Angular-Error-Handler')
    })).pipe(
      tap(
        (_response: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          // nothing to do ... ... used for sending anyway...
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          if (doSpecificHandling) {
            //handle error for specific case
          } else {
            //handle error for generic case
          }
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

With the request:

```
this.http.get<MyInfo>(`getlastInfo/${id}`, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Angular-Error-Handler', 'diff'),
}).toPromise();
```

Comment: Yeah - that's the complete code which finally worked. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a fragile way of doing it, but one way might be to inspect the URL in the interceptor and conditionally execute the logic in the interceptor.

```
@Injectable()
export class HTTPRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(
        (_response: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          // nothing to do ... ... used for sending anyway...
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if(req.url === "some_url"){
                //handle error for specific case
            }else{
                //handle error for generic case
            }
        }
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: Yeah... but isn't there some _better_ way to do it? Cuz the url might change in the code...

Answer (score 0):

A simple but dirty way

```
@Injectable()
export class HTTPRequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
 if(req.url.contains('getlastInfo')){
 //specific handling
 } else {
  //normal handling
 }

}
```

You can also  do the check with `req.body` or `req.headers`by setting for example a specific key value in your header.

Comment: but won't the headers be as well sent?

Comment: yes it will be sent, but not interpreted by the back

Comment: and you can always replace them in your interceptor